# Нужно найти длину списка после первого минимального элемента элемента в списке Python

Tags: python, list

```
spisok = [1,2,3,4,7,10,21,-15,25,6,12,13,19,23,18]

for i in spisok:
    i = min(spisok)
print(spisok.index(i))
```

`i` = минимальный элемент списка
нужно после него с помощью цикла найти длину списка и также найти максимальный элемент списка и также с помощью цикла после максимального элемента найти длину списка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если только циклом, то так можно.
Правда из задания толком не понятно, какую длину списка и когда искать

```
spisok = [1,2,3,4,7,10,21,-15,25,6,12,13,19,23,18]

   


for i in spisok:
    i = min(spisok)
m = spisok.index(i)
counter = 0
max = spisok[m + 1]
for i in range(m + 1, len(spisok)):
    counter += 1
    if max < spisok[i]:
        max = spisok[i]
print(m)
print(counter)
print(max)
```